# Can I reset Windows mail invitations?

Tags: email

I've received quite a few invitations from emails, some of which I've marked 'Accept' and some 'Deny.' Since I marked some Denied, it won't allow the leader to send me further invites for those meetings. It's really a cluster bomb right now and I need to completely remove all previous Accepted/Denied invites from my calendar. I've tried opening the Calendar app and deleting them there, but they are retained after deletion. I've also tried finding the emails in my Trash folder, but some are missing. I've also tried deleting the accounts and re-adding them without luck. Is there a way to reset ALL invites?